# Mongo/Mongoose - How to edit nested structure

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection that looks like this. Each Object within "days" is it's own "day" document. It is not broken down further than that. Here is the structure:

```
 days: [
        {
            day: 'Sunday', 
            slots: [
                {time: '12:00am', event: null}, {time: '1:00am', event: null}, {time: '2:00am', event: null}, {time: '3:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '4:00am', event: null}, {time: '5:00am', event: null}, {time: '6:00am', event: null}, {time: '7:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '8:00am', event: null}, {time: '9:00am', event: null}, {time: '10:00am', event: null}, {time: '11:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '12:00pm', event: null}, {time: '1:00pm', event: null}, {time: '2:00pm', event: null}, {time: '3:00pm', event: null}, 
                {time: '4:00pm', event: null}, {time: '5:00pm', event: null}, {time: '6:00pm', event: null}, {time: '7:00pm', event: null}, 
                {time: '8:00pm', event: null}, {time: '9:00pm', event: null}, {time: '10:00pm', event: null}, {time: '11:00pm', event: null}, 
            ]
        },
        {
            day: 'Monday', 
            slots: [
                {time: '12:00am', event: null}, {time: '1:00am', event: null}, {time: '2:00am', event: null}, {time: '3:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '4:00am', event: null}, {time: '5:00am', event: null}, {time: '6:00am', event: null}, {time: '7:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '8:00am', event: null}, {time: '9:00am', event: null}, {time: '10:00am', event: null}, {time: '11:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '12:00pm', event: null}, {time: '1:00pm', event: null}, {time: '2:00pm', event: null}, {time: '3:00pm', event: null}, 
                {time: '4:00pm', event: null}, {time: '5:00pm', event: null}, {time: '6:00pm', event: null}, {time: '7:00pm', event: null}, 
                {time: '8:00pm', event: null}, {time: '9:00pm', event: null}, {time: '10:00pm', event: null}, {time: '11:00pm', event: null}, 
            ]
        },
        {
            day: 'Tuesday', 
            slots: [
                {time: '12:00am', event: null}, {time: '1:00am', event: null}, {time: '2:00am', event: null}, {time: '3:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '4:00am', event: null}, {time: '5:00am', event: null}, {time: '6:00am', event: null}, {time: '7:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '8:00am', event: null}, {time: '9:00am', event: null}, {time: '10:00am', event: null}, {time: '11:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '12:00pm', event: null}, {time: '1:00pm', event: null}, {time: '2:00pm', event: null}, {time: '3:00pm', event: null}, 
                {time: '4:00pm', event: null}, {time: '5:00pm', event: null}, {time: '6:00pm', event: null}, {time: '7:00pm', event: null}, 
                {time: '8:00pm', event: null}, {time: '9:00pm', event: null}, {time: '10:00pm', event: null}, {time: '11:00pm', event: null}, 
            ]
        },
        {
            day: 'Wednesday', 
            slots: [
                {time: '12:00am', event: null}, {time: '1:00am', event: null}, {time: '2:00am', event: null}, {time: '3:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '4:00am', event: null}, {time: '5:00am', event: null}, {time: '6:00am', event: null}, {time: '7:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '8:00am', event: null}, {time: '9:00am', event: null}, {time: '10:00am', event: null}, {time: '11:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '12:00pm', event: null}, {time: '1:00pm', event: null}, {time: '2:00pm', event: null}, {time: '3:00pm', event: null}, 
                {time: '4:00pm', event: null}, {time: '5:00pm', event: null}, {time: '6:00pm', event: null}, {time: '7:00pm', event: null}, 
                {time: '8:00pm', event: null}, {time: '9:00pm', event: null}, {time: '10:00pm', event: null}, {time: '11:00pm', event: null}, 
            ]
        },
        {
            day: 'Thursday', 
            slots: [
                {time: '12:00am', event: null}, {time: '1:00am', event: null}, {time: '2:00am', event: null}, {time: '3:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '4:00am', event: null}, {time: '5:00am', event: null}, {time: '6:00am', event: null}, {time: '7:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '8:00am', event: null}, {time: '9:00am', event: null}, {time: '10:00am', event: null}, {time: '11:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '12:00pm', event: null}, {time: '1:00pm', event: null}, {time: '2:00pm', event: null}, {time: '3:00pm', event: null}, 
                {time: '4:00pm', event: null}, {time: '5:00pm', event: null}, {time: '6:00pm', event: null}, {time: '7:00pm', event: null}, 
                {time: '8:00pm', event: null}, {time: '9:00pm', event: null}, {time: '10:00pm', event: null}, {time: '11:00pm', event: null}, 
            ]
        },
        {
            day: 'Friday', 
            slots: [
                {time: '12:00am', event: null}, {time: '1:00am', event: null}, {time: '2:00am', event: null}, {time: '3:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '4:00am', event: null}, {time: '5:00am', event: null}, {time: '6:00am', event: null}, {time: '7:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '8:00am', event: null}, {time: '9:00am', event: null}, {time: '10:00am', event: null}, {time: '11:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '12:00pm', event: null}, {time: '1:00pm', event: null}, {time: '2:00pm', event: null}, {time: '3:00pm', event: null}, 
                {time: '4:00pm', event: null}, {time: '5:00pm', event: null}, {time: '6:00pm', event: null}, {time: '7:00pm', event: null}, 
                {time: '8:00pm', event: null}, {time: '9:00pm', event: null}, {time: '10:00pm', event: null}, {time: '11:00pm', event: null}, 
            ]
        },
        {
            day: 'Saturday', 
            slots: [
                {time: '12:00am', event: null}, {time: '1:00am', event: null}, {time: '2:00am', event: null}, {time: '3:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '4:00am', event: null}, {time: '5:00am', event: null}, {time: '6:00am', event: null}, {time: '7:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '8:00am', event: null}, {time: '9:00am', event: null}, {time: '10:00am', event: null}, {time: '11:00am', event: null}, 
                {time: '12:00pm', event: null}, {time: '1:00pm', event: null}, {time: '2:00pm', event: null}, {time: '3:00pm', event: null}, 
                {time: '4:00pm', event: null}, {time: '5:00pm', event: null}, {time: '6:00pm', event: null}, {time: '7:00pm', event: null}, 
                {time: '8:00pm', event: null}, {time: '9:00pm', event: null}, {time: '10:00pm', event: null}, {time: '11:00pm', event: null}, 
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I would like to edit the event field that is nested inside this json. How would I got about doing that? I have a Day model. But it's not broken down further than that. I was thinking of using findOneAndUpdate, but I'm can't figure out how to drill down so I'm in the proper time slot. The endpoint has access to the day, the time and the value to set event to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `$` operator to set the nested object in array

```
db.days.update(
    {day: 'Monday', 'slots.time': '12:00am'}
    {$set: {'slots.$.event': 'your new value'}}
);
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I appreciate the help